# Selenium- scroll down in div popup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, scroll

I have scrolled down in div popup in using following command

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",addToCartPopup, 250);
```

However, I do not have understanding of the above command i.e.
"arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",addToCartPopup, 250

Can someone please explain this in detail

Answer (score 0):

following the documentation of executeScript:

> executeScript(java.lang.String script, java.lang.Object... args)
>
> Executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window.

You provide the script and additional array of args.

Based on your execution

- arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1]; -- this is the script.
- arguments[0]  -- first argument is the element you provide. *addToCartPopup*, he will trigger the function *scrollTop*
- arguments[1] -- is the second argument, actually the the scroll value, which in your case is *250*